# Windows Trail on moving HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a cool effect on my website using HTML, CSS, and maybe some JavaScript.

I want to use an image and as my cursor,
and I want it to leave a trail behind as I move my mouse around the page.

I'm not very experienced with JavaScript, so I'd appreciate it if you could show me some examples.

The image I want to use is an old Windows error message, and I want to fill up the page with it.

Can anyone help me achieve this effect?

[image: image of old windows error that i'm going for]

Thank you!

Comment: So do you just want to add an image to the cursor position when it moves?

Comment: @DOOP I don't think you will be able to accomplish this with a native cursor; probably you will need to introduce a custom cursor as an image or SVG and then use a solution like the one posted below as an answer.

Comment: @Mrbisquit yeah pretty much!

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately for now native CSS `cursor` can't be used for this type of things natively *(for example: image need to be very small like a icon)*

---

but if we use `<img>` approach then hopefully we can find a solution:

### TLDR solution:

Without any complex math or javascript,

we can use the native CSS property `transition-duration`,

and get some results that are very smooth.

```css
transition-duration: calc(
                          var(--i) * 0.02s /* increase the 0.02s if you want more effect, for example to 0.05s */
                         );
```

### here the result I got:

[image]

### demo code below:

```js
const popups = document.querySelectorAll(".popup");

// just a simple move event, the magic is in the css
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  popups.forEach((popup) => {
    popup.style.left = `${e.clientX - popup.clientWidth  / 2}px`;
    popup.style.top =  `${e.clientY - popup.clientHeight / 2}px`;
  });
});
```

```css
.popup-container {
  position: relative;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50vh;
  transition-duration: calc(var(--i) * 0.02s); /* here magic happens */
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-container">
  <img style="--i: 5;" class="popup" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNu91.png" alt="" />
  <img style="--i: 4;" class="popup" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNu91.png" alt="" />
  <img style="--i: 3;" class="popup" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNu91.png" alt="" />
  <img style="--i: 2;" class="popup" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNu91.png" alt="" />
  <img style="--i: 1;" class="popup" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNu91.png" alt="" />
  <img style="--i: 0;" class="popup" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNu91.png" alt="" />
</div>
```